# Bootstrap navbar doesnt expand after collapsing

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and JS and I've almost exactly followed the documentation but for some reason my button doesn't expand on click.

I've checked other similar answers on SO, but all of them were due to incorrect CDN's. I've used the one provided on the official bootstrap docs site.

For reference, here are the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) and here is the 
CDN I am [using.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/)

Here is the fiddle [url](https://jsfiddle.net/j7z2qfkt/).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YelpCamp</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">YelpCamp</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">SignUp</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the docs on Bootstrap, you will see that bootstrap.min.js needs to be at the end.

> jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.

Comment: Ok. It works now. But can you tell me why is it so? Like why does the ordering affect the functionality?

Comment: @KaranSingh Because you put the script tags inside <head> block, each script is fully loaded and processed before moving to the next script. Bootstrap requires the jQuery but at the time of processing the Bootstrap script, the jQuery functions are not loaded yet and therefore creating your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to bottom of your `<head>` tag.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Full Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YelpCamp</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">YelpCamp</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">SignUp</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery.js must appear before bootstrap.js. And usually the script tags are put in the bottom, just before the closing </body> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import JQuery first before bootstrap.min.js

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```